# My Mac suddenly no longer able to resolve DNS address when connecting to WIFI, but still able to ping to physical address. Why?

Tags: network, wifi, dns

I am usually able to connect to Wifi or iPhone USB tethering and browse the internet with no problem. But one day, I'm unable to browse using a Wifi connection. When I try to ping, I'm able to ping to 8.8.8.8, but I'm unable to ping to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). I tried to resolve using:

- `nslookup www.google.com 8.8.8.8`
- `dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com`
- `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist`

All has no result. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was because I uncheck the option "Disable unless needed" on the iPhone USB connection tethering. I unchecked that because sometimes the iPhone connection gets unstable and I notice the Mac tries to connect to local Wifi instead to find better connection. I want Mac to stay connected using iPhone USB connection. But turns out unchecking this option cause *my Mac* to stop able to resolve DNS. I have asked this in another Stack Exchange network (I forgot which one) but nobody able to resolve this issue. So I posted it here hoping to help people who might stuck with the same issue in the future.

[image]

The box should stay "checked". Do not uncheck/untick this box.